# Adding new column to pandas DataFrame results in NaN

Tags: python, pandas-groupby

I have a pandas DataFrame `data` with the following transaction data:

```
           A         date
0      M000833  2016-08-01
1      M000833  2016-08-01
2      M000833  2016-08-02
3      M000833  2016-08-02 
4      M000511  2016-08-05
```

I want a new column with the count of number of visits (multiple visits per day should be treated as 1) per consumer.

So I tried this:

```
import pandas as pd
data['noofvisits'] = data.groupby(['A'])['date'].nunique()
```

When I just run the statement without assigning it to the DataFrame, I get a pandas series with the desired output. However, the above statement result in:

```
           A         date       noofvisits
0      M000833  2016-08-01         NaN         
1      M000833  2016-08-01         NaN
2      M000833  2016-08-02         NaN
3      M000833  2016-08-02         NaN
4      M000511  2016-08-05         NaN
```

The expected output is:

```
           A         date       noofvisits
0      M000833  2016-08-01         2         
1      M000833  2016-08-01         2
2      M000833  2016-08-02         2
3      M000833  2016-08-02         2
4      M000511  2016-08-05         1
```

What is wrong with this approach? Why does the column noofvisits results in NAs rather than the count values?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#transformation) to generate a `Series` with it's index aligned to the original df:

```
In[32]:
df['noofvisits'] = df.groupby(['A'])['date'].transform('nunique')
df

Out[32]: 
             A        date  noofvisits
index                                 
0      M000833  2016-08-01           2
1      M000833  2016-08-01           2
2      M000833  2016-08-02           2
3      M000833  2016-08-02           2
4      M000511  2016-08-05           1
```

The problem with direct assigning is that you're `group`ing on column `'A'` so this becomes the index of the `groupby` aggregation, you then try to assign to your df but the indices don't agree hence the `NaN` column values.

Also even if the index values did agree the shape is different anyway:

```
In[33]:
df.groupby(['A'])['date'].nunique()

Out[33]: 
A
M000511    1
M000833    2
Name: date, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Any pointers on how to tackle a similar scenario using lambda function instead of nunique?

Comment: `df['noofvisits'] = df.groupby(['A'])['date'].transform(lambda x: do_something(x))`